# Deploying multiple wars to Tomcat using maven is not working

Tags: java, deployment, tomcat7, maven-3, war

I have a Parent project which include 3 modules 
          COMMON,Instant and ART

Packaging of Instant and ART is war

When I am running mvn tomcat:run its only running Instant not ART.

Could you please let me know what I have to use to run both of the wars.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: do you trying to start it using console? as I know, if you have a few modules working as one app, you need to have one app which will be as a parent for all your modules

Comment: Yes, I am using terminal(In Mac) to run the command. Parent project packaging is pom

Comment: show your .poms of all the modules. it is also easyer to deploy it from the ide

Comment: I am facing some other issues with IDE so I am trying for terminal